# Stuck with parsing json data in Java

Tags: java, android, json

I hope someone might be able to help me. I am trying to parse following json file:

```
{
"seminar":[{
    "categoryid": "1",
    "cpe": "13",
    "inventory": [
        "Discussion",
        "Value x",
        "Value y"
    ],
    "teachers": [{
        "titel": "Dipl.-Ing.",
        "company": "XY",
        "name": "Test",
        "id": "3"
    }]
}]
}
```

I am lost with parsing the teachers data in...

```
private static final String TAG_TEACHERS = "teachers";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";

for(int i = 0; i < seminar.length(); i++){
JSONObject c = seminar.getJSONObject(i);

teachers = c.getJSONArray(TAG_TEACHERS);
for(int z = 0; z < teachers.length(); z++){                 
JSONObject d = teachers.getJSONObject(z);
String title  = d.getString(TAG_TITLE);
Log.d("JSONParsingActivity", title);
```

I get the error System.err(1010): org.json.JSONException: Value null at teachers of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray.

What did I do wrong? As I understand from the JSON documentation, teachers is an JSON Array and not an Object. Is somebody able to help me?

Comment: what are you doing? :) let Edit the Question in right format! you always doing it wrong

Comment: I am new to this and I didn't understand the instructions right, so I am trying my best now.

Comment: There should be TAG_teachers as parameter at c.getJSONArray(TAG_DOZENTEN) instead of TAG_DOZENTEN. If its a typo kindly correct it.

Comment: Pls can you post the actual code snippet and the log.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using wrong tag.
teachers = c.getJSONArray(TAG_DOZENTEN);

Shouldn't it be TAG_teachers instead of TAG_DOZENTEN?

Comment: I was referring to private static final String TAG_teachers = "teachers";

Comment: +1, good find! Mixing languages messed with my reading ability here.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a answer to your specific problem but anyway.
Do you need to parse this manually? Why not use a mapper, like Jackson for example.

http://jackson.codehaus.org/0.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html

Much smoother!

Comment: Much better idea to use a mapper over manual parsing. Personally I like [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: yes I need to parse this manually. But thanks for the hint anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse given JSON String as:

```
JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject("YOUR_JSON_STRING");

JSONArray jArrseminar = jObj.getJSONArray("seminar");
for(int i = 0; i < jArrseminar.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jobject = jArrseminar.getJSONObject(i);

    String strcategoryid=jobject.getString("categoryid");
    String strcpe=jobject.getString("cpe");

    JSONArray jArrinventory = jobject.getJSONArray("inventory");
    for(int j = 0; j < jArrinventory.length(); j++){

        // access all inventory value here
    }


    JSONArray jArrteachers = jobject.getJSONArray("teachers");
    for(int j = 0; j < jArrteachers.length(); j++){
        JSONObject jobjectteachers = jArrteachers.getJSONObject(i);

        // access all teachers value here
    String strtitel=jobjectteachers.getString("titel");
    String strcompany=jobjectteachers.getString("company");
    String strname=jobjectteachers.getString("name");
    String strid=jobjectteachers.getString("id");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this throws same error: Value null at teachers of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray.

Comment: @user1854707 : this is 200%  right parsing for JSON as your provided in Question if you post modified code then this will more helpful in solving your issue quickly thanks

Comment: @user1854707 : see my edit answer full parsing of teachers Array

Comment: with inventory it works fine,inventory is an Array of type  "inventory": [], but teachers is an Object right? As it is of type    "teachers": [{ }]

Comment: @user1854707 : you can see my edit answer this will work perfectly.becuase teachers is an array and it contain an JSONObject at index 0